# Editor User Role can't see other users media

Tags: uploads, user-roles, media-library

The Editor role can't view/access other users media. Apparently, the website was working good everywhere but a few days later we noticed that.

If we assign *Administration* roles, it works.,

**Actions performed without success:**

1. Disabled all plugins
2. Created new users to check if only the old users are affected.
3. Add new media
4. Rename media

Comment: What? Did you copy someone else’s answer?

Comment: @vikrantzilpe what are you talking about man?